# $\|x_n\|_1 = \|T(x_n)\|_\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let's define functional :

$$T: l^1 \ni(x_n) \rightarrow(\sum_{k=1}^nx_k)_{n=1}^\infty \in c$$

where c is a set of converged sequences. I want to prove or find counterexample of $\|x_n\|_1 = \|T(x_n)\|_\infty$

Let's rewrite $T(x_n)$:

$$T(x_n) = (x_1, x_1+x_2, x_1 + x_2 + x_3,...)$$

Since on the $n$ -th element of sequence $T(x_n)$ we have sum of $n$ positive numbers, it implies that
$$\|T(x_n)\|_\infty=\|(x_1, x_1+x_2,x_1 + x_2 +x_3,...)\|_\infty =  \mid \sum_{n=1}^\infty x_n \mid \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty|x_n|=\|x_n\|_1$$

But I have no idea how can I prove or disprove reveresed inequality. I tried to choose sequences $x_n = 2^{-n}$ or $x_n = -2^{-n}$ but those two didn't disprove the thesis. Could you please help me with solving this problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sequence $x=(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ defined by
$$x_1=1, \quad x_2=-1, \quad \text{and } x_k=0 \text{ for } k\geq 3$$

Then
$$||x||_1=2$$

but $T(x)=(1,0,0,0,...)$, so you get
$$||T(x)||_{\infty}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

Take the sequence
$$x_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}, \quad n=1,2,3,\dots .$$
We have
$$\| x_n\|_1=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|=1, $$
and
$$\|T(x_n)\|_\infty = \sup_{N \geq 1} \left| \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \right|=\sup_{N \geq 1} \left| \frac{1}{3} \left(\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^N-1\right) \right|=\sup_{N \geq 1} \frac{1-(-1/2)^N}{3} = \frac{1}{2}. $$